# How to give a scope name as like $scope.username.firstname in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

*Please check the bellow snippet*

**here is the sample controller**

```
angular.module("sampleApp").controller("transactionController",function($scope){ 

    $scope.audit.lob = {   
            "type": "select", 
            "name": "Service",
            "value": "-SELECT-",
            "values":['-SELECT-','TRAVEL','CARGO','AIRPORT','TRANSGUARD']
    };
});
```

**and this is my html code**

```
<select id="lob_id" class="set-width"
        ng-model="audit.lob.value"
        ng-options="lob for lob in audit.lob.values"
        name="lob" required>
</select>
```

*By doing like this I am getting error*

> $scope.audit is undefined

*if i remove dots in scope name its working fine.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
$scope.audit.lob = {   
        "type": "select", 
        "name": "Service",
        "value": "-SELECT-",
        "values":['-SELECT-','TRAVEL','CARGO','AIRPORT','TRANSGUARD']
};
```

will not work because as it says `audit` is not defined.

Try

```
$scope.audit = {
    lob: {
        "type": "select", 
        "name": "Service",
        "value": "-SELECT-",
        "values":['-SELECT-','TRAVEL','CARGO','AIRPORT','TRANSGUARD']
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a valid object (https://repl.it/BGdR) so maybe you can show what you wrote exactly

Comment: @Joy, it's perfectly valid. The only reason to use quotes is when your key name isn't a valid js identifier. Actually none of the keys is this code need quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Declare in controller like

```
$scope.username={firstname:'Joy'}
```

and in html fetch like

```
{{username.firstname}}
```

Comment: please help me as per above given example in question @Paresh

Answer (score 0):

Please check the plunker, You can achieve it in [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/VjLige/preview) way.